# passing pdf file name using php variable in html

Tags: php, html

I am creating a pdf file using php and fpdf
and also it is saved server
I want to show it in html 
error comes in embed source

My php code is as follows

```
    <?php
        ..... some processing
        $m_pfile='payslips-'.$m_mthyear.'-'.$m_pname.'.pdf';
        $pdf->Output($m_pfile);
        ?>

        $m_pfile comes as 'payslips-Dec-17-abc.pdf'

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head></head>
       <body>
          <div id="content">
             <div align="center">
                <a href='../payslips.php'><img src = '../images/close-icon.png' height='50' width='50' alt = 'close' title = 'close'/></a>
                <div align="center">
                   <embed src='$m_pfile' width=810px height=1180px>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide more info about the 'html error' you get.

Comment: there is no error but pdf file is shown as $m_pfile instead of payslips-Dec-17-abc.pdf

Comment: Not reproducible: https://eval.in/934189

Comment: `<embed src=value=...` - what's going on here? This isn't valid markup.